# VBA Json Parse response with JsonConverter

Tags: json, vba

Posting request API to Statistics Canada.
The Response string I'm getting is complex (at least to me) and I can not extract any value from it.

Tried many syntax possible to only get the "cansimId" without success.

My goal would be to list (array loop) the "dimensionPositionId":2 ("Principal statistics") and get all ("memberNameEn")

Many thanks! :)

Here's a sample from the response. Too big to post it all here +100K.txt:

```
[
  {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "object": {
      "responseStatusCode": 0,
      "productId": "16100047",
      "cansimId": "304-0014",
      "cubeTitleEn": "Manufacturers' sales, inventories, orders and inventory to sales ratios, by industry (dollars unless otherwise noted)",
      "cubeTitleFr": "Stocks, ventes, commandes et rapport des stocks sur les ventes pour les industries manufacturières, selon l'industrie (dollars sauf indication contraire)",
      "cubeStartDate": "1992-01-01",
      "cubeEndDate": "2021-08-01",
      "frequencyCode": 6,
      "nbSeriesCube": 2798,
      "nbDatapointsCube": 935808,
      "releaseTime": "2021-10-14T08:30",
      "archiveStatusCode": "2",
      "archiveStatusEn": "CURRENT - a cube available to the public and that is current",
      "archiveStatusFr": "ACTIF - un cube qui est disponible au public et qui est toujours mise a jour",
      "subjectCode": [
        "1699",
        "230402",
        "330303",
        "451003"
      ],
      "surveyCode": [
        "2101"
      ],
      "dimension": [
        {
          "dimensionPositionId": 1,
          "dimensionNameEn": "Geography",
          "dimensionNameFr": "Géographie",
          "hasUom": false,
          "member": [
            {
              "memberId": 1,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Canada",
              "memberNameFr": "Canada",
              "classificationCode": "11124",
              "classificationTypeCode": "1",
              "geoLevel": 0,
              "vintage": 2016,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dimensionPositionId": 2,
          "dimensionNameEn": "Principal statistics",
          "dimensionNameFr": "Les statistiques principales",
          "hasUom": true,
          "member": [
            {
              "memberId": 1,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Sales of goods manufactured (shipments)",
              "memberNameFr": "Ventes de biens fabriqués (livraisons)",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 2,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "New orders, estimated values of orders received during month",
              "memberNameFr": "Nouvelles commandes, valeur estimative des commandes reçues durant le mois",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 3,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Unfilled orders, estimated values of orders at end of month",
              "memberNameFr": "Commandes en carnet, valeur estimative des commandes à la fin du mois",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 4,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Raw materials, fuel, supplies, components, estimated values at end of month",
              "memberNameFr": "Matières premières, combustibles, fournitures et composantes, valeur estimative à la fin du mois",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 5,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Goods or work in process, estimated values at end of month",
              "memberNameFr": "Biens en cours de fabrication ou travaux en cours, valeur estimative à la fin du mois",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 6,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Finished goods manufactured, estimated values at end of  month",
              "memberNameFr": "Produits finis fabriqués, valeur estimative à la fin du mois",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 7,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Total inventory, estimated values of total inventory at end of the month",
              "memberNameFr": "Total des stocks, valeur estimative des stocks à la fin du mois",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 81
            },
            {
              "memberId": 8,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Ratio of total inventory to sales",
              "memberNameFr": "Rapport du total des stocks aux ventes",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 270
            },
            {
              "memberId": 9,
              "parentMemberId": null,
              "memberNameEn": "Ratio of finished goods to sales",
              "memberNameFr": "Rapport des produits finis aux ventes",
              "classificationCode": null,
              "classificationTypeCode": null,
              "geoLevel": null,
              "vintage": null,
              "terminated": 0,
              "memberUomCode": 270
            }
          ]
        },
```

And here's the code:

```
Dim Request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim Body As String
Dim Json As Object

Body = "[{" & Chr(34) & "productId" & Chr(34) & ":16100047}]"

Request.Open "POST", "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/wds/rest/getCubeMetadata", False
Request.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
Request.send Body

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Request.ResponseText)

'Debug.print Json("status") 'Error !!!!
'Debug.Print Json("cansimId") 'Error!!!!
'Debug.print Json("object")("cansimId") 'Error!!!!
```

Comment: I found out that if I remove the first and last square brakets "[" "]" from the response, I can now read ...

Comment: Your input goes `[{status: "...", "object": { ... }}] `. There is no `Json("status")`, you top-level object is an *array*. You need to use `Json(0)` to get the first array item. You can use `Json(0)("status")` to get the status of the first array item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's Tomalak, you were right!
One thing... All my arrays seems to be 'option base 1' (although not specify!)
So  Json(1)("status")  is now working.

Finaly got what I needed:

```
Dim ColStatPrinc As Collection
Dim StatPrinc As Dictionary
x = 1
Set ColStatPrinc = Json(1)("object")("dimension")(2)("member")
With Sheets(1)
    For Each StatPrinc In ColStatPrinc
        .Cells(x, 1) = StatPrinc("memberId")
        .Cells(x, 2) = StatPrinc("memberNameFr")
        x = x + 1
    Next StatPrinc
End With
```